# IBM Cloud Function - Connecting to Kubernetes container

Tags: kubernetes, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-functions, ibm-cloud-kubernetes

I want to connect from an IBM Cloud Function to a Kubernetes container so that the Cloud Function can query a Rest API that is in a Kubernetes cluster in the same resource group. The Kubernetes Cluster has the public ip disabled, just the private ip is nabled.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Please provide more details. Is the REST API exposed / accessible outside the cluster? Are the cluster and the functions in the same region and data center?

Answer (score 1):

There is many ways of accessing Kubernetes Api, you can read about I think most of them [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/access-cluster-api/).

I will just mentioned few that might be useful in your case.

One would be using a [python client](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python) which can be installed using `pip install kubernetes`.
For more information about the library you should check [this page](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python).

You need to copy over the kubeconfig flie from the Kubernetes cluster over IBM Cloud Function, once that is done your basic code might look like this:

```py
from kubernetes import client, config

config.load_kube_config()

v1=client.CoreV1Api()
print("Listing pods with their IPs:")
ret = v1.list_pod_for_all_namespaces(watch=False)
for i in ret.items:
    print("%s\t%s\t%s" % (i.status.pod_ip, i.metadata.namespace, i.metadata.name))
```

You can find more examples for Python at their [GitHub page](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/tree/master/examples).

There are also other libraries like [Java client](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/access-cluster-api/#java-client), [dotnet client](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/access-cluster-api/#dotnet-client), [JavaScript client](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/access-cluster-api/#javascript-client).

Full list of official libraries is available on [Client Libraries](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/client-libraries/) also they are mentioning the community-maintained ones.